# Limiting a view based on authentication by writing qualified username

Tags: bcs, claims-based-auth, bdc

This article http://www.thesharepointbar.com/?p=340 how to limit a read on a user in BCS, but we can't find the correct syntax for fba-users. (MS Quote: If the login mode for the user is claims-based, then the value passed is the unique value that identifies the user (for example, membership: username, username@provider.com)).

So we asked ourselves how to write qualifiedusername behind the scenes with @Username in a create part of BCS (and see what it wrote). But we couldn't find a way for that either.
Thanks in advance.
Rob

Answer (score 1):

Given a login name (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName) of "i:0#.f|fbaprovider|user" the following will result in "user"

```
string result = LoginName;
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(LoginName))
{
    result = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.Local.DecodeClaim(LoginName).Value;
}
```